# Estimating delivery time of GRO's new PDF format?

Tags: death-records, united-kingdom

I have ordered a death certificate over the new PDF format from the GRO the other day and have been given an estimate date of 15th for it to be sent to my email; that's 5 working days.

Can anyone who has used the service already let me know if this estimate if accurate?

Does it normally take five working days or may it be done sooner?

I imagine this is a maximum expected time to cover any delays.

Comment: The answers to this question are not going to be accurate for long, hence the downvote.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl: True. I'd expect it to be valid for the duration of the current extended pilot phase, though, unless demand soars. If the pilot is replaced by a permanent service, then turnaround times may change. But the GRO's estimates of service times do at least seem fairly accurate.

Comment: Downvoted for the same reason already stated. The questions and answers don't have any long-term usefulness and don't involve skillbuilding or doing research. This is a question that could have been asked in the chat room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just from personal experience... I recently placed orders and received PDFs as follows:

```
Ordered     Received    WrkDays
17 Oct      23 Oct      5
19 Oct      25 Oct      5
30 Oct      03 Nov      4
04 Dec      07 Dec      4
```

So two of those orders were processed in 5 working days, and two were faster.

(Updated after finding GRO response in my spam filter, so remarks on later delivery were unfounded.)

Comment: Just to confirm @AndyW's experience, I've just received my 3rd PDF certificate from the GRO. All three arrived on the 5th working day.